# (C++) Can't get deque insert() to work, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, insert, deque

I'm getting an error on the `insert()` part here, and I dunno what I am doing wrong. I've tried different parameters and number of parameters but nothing seems to work.

`m_oGameObjectList` is a deque of IGameObjects (base class).
`m_sPosition` is a struct with 3 ints (X, Y, Z).
`gameObject` is the reference to an object derived from `IGameObject`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_oGameObjectList.size(); i++)
{
    if (gameObject.m_sPosition.Z > m_oGameObjectList[i].m_sPosition.Z)
    {
        m_oGameObjectList.insert(i, gameObject);
        i = m_oGameObjectList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insert` takes an `iterator`. Use:

```
m_oGameObjectList.insert(m_oGameObjectList.begin() + i, gameObject);
```

You'll also need to use pointers in your `deque`, right now you're slicing - inserting a copy of the `IGameObject` part of `gameObject`

Answer (score 0):

trying to insert an object derived from IGameObject into a deque<IGameObject> won't work as the deque is trying to store a copy of the object in the reference, not the reference itself.

Most of the time, if your trying to store an class hiearchy into a container, you do so by having the container of pointers to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `insert` should pass an iterator (not an integer index) into the deque. One way you can convert an integer index to a deque iterator is via:

```
my_deque_iterator iter = m_oGameObjectList.begin();
std::advance(m_oGameObjectList, i);
```

... though there are several other solutions that work equally well.

You can also use deque functions like `push_back` and `push_front` which just take the object you want to put at the front or back of the deque, respectively.